# Como obter a página depois da autenticação com requests?

Tags: aplicação-web, web-scraping, python-requests

Estou tentando fazer um web scraping em python. Meu código é o seguinte:

---

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = requests.Session()
payload = {'username':'[xxxxx]',
'password':'[xxxxx]'
}
url = 'http://portalservicos.jucec.ce.gov.br/auth/realms/Portal_Interno/login-actions/authenticate?code='
'NmiD0KPHHHbIUuEfrayVTQihFq8PgNHoun0tR8Rtp0M.97621447-8553-43f8-b505-bee4d488dc16&execution=e489f6d8-a24c-'
'400b-a121-b4dd05035c47'
s = session.post(url,data=payload,headers = dict(referer=url))

---

A resposta é 200, mas a página obtida é a mesma de antes do login.

Incluir essa linha:

---

pagina=session.get('http://portalservicos.jucec.ce.gov.br/srm/principal.jsf')
soup = BeautifulSoup(pagina.text, 'html.parser')

---

Também não funcionou, é como se o login não tivesse sido feito, O conteúdo da página é o mesmo de antes do login.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Os parâmetros `code` e `execution` são dinâmicos. Raspe primeiro a página de login, pegue a action do form e submeta o login para essa action na mesma `session`. Essa pode não ser a solução, mas é por onde você deve começar.

Answer (score -1):

A response que te dá status 200 também tem uma propriedade url

faça o teste:

```
if response.history:
print("Request was redirected")
for resp in response.history:
    print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
print("Final destination:")
print(response.status_code, response.url)
```

else:
print("Request was not redirected")